# How to fix StreamWriter error "cannot implicitly convert type string to System.IO.StreamWriter"

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I'm using C# in Visual Studio 2017 Community.

I have a working, fully functional program that I am trying to optimize.  In a nutshell, the program reads text and numbers from text files, does some math and reformatting, then outputs to a new text file.

The part I am trying to optimize is the way lines of text are written to the output file.  Here is what works:

```
using System.IO

// Let's start building the MA output text file now.
// Designate an output file --- put it in same directory as original files
// give MA file ame name as the original file -- but different extension.

maOutFile = dir + "\\" + serialNumber[f] + ".ma";

//Create MA header lines and write to file.

string maHeaderLine1 = "TITLE: S/N:" + serialNumber[f] + "\n";
string maHeaderLine2 = "ENGLISH(IN)/METRIC(MM) INDICATOR :IN-P\n";

// Open up the file for writing
File.WriteAllText(maOutFile, maHeaderLine1);
File.AppendAllText(maOutFile, maHeaderLine2);
```

The above code works fine.  My concern is that it's not very efficient, especially over a slow network.  It opens and closes the file every time it writes to it.

So, to make this run faster, I thought I would try StreamWriter.

My StreamWriter code looks like this:

```
// Designate an output file --- put it in same directory as the original files
// give MA file same name as the original file -- with different extension.

// maOutFile = dir + "\\" + serialNumber[f] + ".ma";

StreamWriter outfile;
outfile = dir + "\\" + serialNumber[f] + ".ma";

//Create MA header lines and write to file.

string maHeaderLine1 = "TITLE: S/N:" + serialNumber[f] + "\n";
string maHeaderLine2 = "ENGLISH(IN)/METRIC(MM) INDICATOR :IN-P\n";

// Open up the file for writing
//File.WriteAllText(maOutFile, maHeaderLine1);
//File.AppendAllText(maOutFile, maHeaderLine2);
outfile.WriteLine(maHeaderLine1);
outfile.WriteLine(maHeaderLine2);
```

Visual Studio doesn't like my new code using StreamWriter.  It puts a red line under everything to the right of the equals sign in the line "outfile = dir + "\" + serialNumber[f] + ".ma";

When I hover my mouse over the redlined code, the message is "cannot implicitly convert type string to System.IO.StreamWriter".

What doesn't it like about my new code?

Comment: Where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a string variable to a StreamWriter object instead of creating a StreamWriter object.

Try the following

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(dir + "\\" + serialNumber[f] + ".ma"))
{
string maHeaderLine1 = "TITLE: S/N:" + serialNumber[f] + "\n";
string maHeaderLine2 = "ENGLISH(IN)/METRIC(MM) INDICATOR :IN-P\n";

// Open up the file for writing
//File.WriteAllText(maOutFile, maHeaderLine1);

sw.WriteLine(maHeaderLine1);
sw.WriteLine(maHeaderLine2);
}
```

Comment: Follow up question: When I first tried implementing this fix, I forgot to close the output file when I was done writing to it.  But the software seemed to do that automatically.  I just now put a close statement at the end -- sw.Close(); -- and it seems to work the same way. Is it closing each file automatically?  Or, are they somehow still "open"?

Comment: The `using` ensures cleanup/closing is done when its scope has finished executing (After `sw.WriteLine(maHeaderLine2)` )

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that your solution performed tremendously over my tortoise-like network at work.  I am now a StreamWriter advocate.  Thank you again so much!    Oh, and I also had a good laugh at myself while implementing your fix.  When I first put your code into my program, I left the lines of text "as is". -- which included the newline character "\n".  So when I ran it the first time, for every line of text I output, I also output a blank line.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign a string to a StreamWriter here:

```
outfile = dir + "\\" + serialNumber[f] + ".ma";
```

And looking at the code you're trying to open a file as a stream, something along the lines of:

```
string outFileDir = dir + "\\" + serialNumber[f] + ".ma";
StreamWriter outFile = new StreamWriter(outFileDir);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string fileName = dir + "\\" + serialNumber[f] + ".ma" ;  
try  
   {  
   using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName))  
      {  
        string maHeaderLine1 = "TITLE: S/N:" + serialNumber[f] + "\n";
        string maHeaderLine2 = "ENGLISH(IN)/METRIC(MM) INDICATOR :IN-P\n";
        writer.Write(maHeaderLine1 + maHeaderLine2);  
      }  
   }  
catch(Exception exp)  
   {  
      Console.Write(exp.Message);  
   }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to add any new solutions to the question--please reserve answers for _novel_ solutions to OP's questions. Furthermore, blocks of code without any explanation or text are rarely useful; it's always appropriate to explain what your code is doing and why that solves OP's problem.